# ActiveMQ - I can't consume a message sent from Camel using InOut pattern

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

ActiveMQ 5.5.1

```
<c:route>
    <c:from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8055/ws/despacho" />
    <c:to uri="bean:despachoHandler" />
    <c:to uri="activemq:queue:copom.out.test" pattern="InOut" />
</c:route>
```

The message appears queued, but I can't consume it.
After some time I get the timeout and the message goes to ActiveMQ.DLQ.

> org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not
>   received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID:
>   Camel-ID-SSP-SGPF-GITSAD-58215-1359134232568-0-3 not received.

If I change it to **pattern="InOnly"** I'm able to consume the message normally.

What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should learn the EIP patterns.

When using InOut you are doing a request-reply EIP pattern
http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

And in this case, a message is sent to a JMS queue, and as you do InOut, then a reply message is expected to be send back to the queue defined in the JMSReply property (which Camel will set to a temporary queue name if not explicit set otherwise).

And if there is no reply message coming back after 20 seconds Camel fails with a timed out exception. You can configure the length of the timeout.

So you have to decide if you are doing a request reply EIP (InOut) or a event message (InOnly)
http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html

Answer (score 1):

We got similar issue when JMSCorrelationID= was set our system and Camel in/out was not able to receive response from Request Reply queue.
On removing JMSCorrelationID= being set by our code, Camel start running successfully receiving message from Request Reply queue.

Comment: This is very helpful. It isn't related to the original question, but helps to understand and explain behavior of the Camel system.

In my case, this header was set because the sending to the outgoing queue message was originating from another queue and the JmsConsumer set the JMSCorrelationID header for it, which makes the JmsProducer generate `JMSReplyTo` header and wait for a response from the outgoing queue.